# How to ignore pace in Angularjs $http request

Tags: angularjs, pace

Im using AngularJS v1.5.8 and Pace.ignore() is not working on $http.get and $http.post mathods.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I guess some more details are needed, like how you've combined AngularJs and pace. Show some code what you've tried so far

Comment: From the Github site: We no longer use this library internally and are focusing our efforts on open sourcing and maintaining projects that we do use and can meaningfully contribute to. https://github.com/HubSpot/pace